# Integral representation of cochains and a theorem of Hopf

Tags: homotopy-theory, cohomology, clifford-algebras

The classical theorem of Hopf asserts that for any
n-dimensional CW-complex $K$, there is an isomorphism
between homotopy classes from $K$ to the sphere $S^n$ and
the nth singular cohomology group:
$$
[K, S^n] \simeq H^n(K, {\bf Z}).
$$

In the one-dimensional case, the isomorphism is given
by an integral when the map is smooth.
For $f:K \rightarrow S^1 \subset {\bf C}$
and $\gamma \in H_1(M, {\bf Z})$,
$$
\langle \gamma,f \rangle = {1 \over 2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} {f' \over f}.
$$
Is there a similar result in higher dimension,
when ${\bf C}$ is replaced by some Clifford algebra?

Comment: I think you'd just integrate the standard volume form pulled back from S^n.